# postgreSQL check constraint and null

Tags: postgresql

I created a table "TEST" and i tried to input some data however i got an error. The error is *ERROR: new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "test_status_check" DETAIL: Failing row contains (5 , 2015-07-21, 15:00:00, I7 , 9 , NULL, NULL).* 
I think it is because of the null of the status. Therefore, i tried put a null in the test table but still not working

```
Create table test(
    clientID CHAR (20),
    startDate date,
    startTime time,
    instructorNO CHAR(20),
    centreID  CHAR(20), 
    status CHAR(4) CHECK (status IN ('Fail','Pass')) NULL,
    reason VARCHAR(400),

    omitted...
    )
```

ERROR: new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "test_status_check" DETAIL: Failing row contains (5 , 2015-07-21, 15:00:00, I7 , 9 , NULL, NULL).

Comment: is this mysql or postegresql??

Comment: Postgres 9.3 accept your syntax, however, really what is it exactly that you want. Postgres, MySQL, and which version??

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since the title clearly says PostgreSQL (and last time I checked, `CHECK` constraints don't work in MySQL anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I've completely changed my mind. Your existing code is valid (and the `NULL` part is unnecessary).

According to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html),

> It should be noted that a check constraint is satisfied if the check expression evaluates to true or the null value. Since most expressions will evaluate to the null value if any operand is null, they will not prevent null values in the constrained columns. To ensure that a column does not contain null values, the not-null constraint described in the next section can be used.

So, something else is messed up. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/3a88c/1/1) for an example of your original code working.

Comment: @Bredan Long when i input some data in the table error occur *Query failed: ERROR: new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "test_status_check" DETAIL: Failing row contains (2 , 2015-04-29, 10:00:00, I2 , 1 , NULL, NULL).*

Comment: @nicholaslui Are you sure you removed the old constraint?

Comment: Hm, weirdly.. your original code works for me on PostgreSQL 9.3.6 :\

Comment: hahaha i solve it out lol i put a '' in NULL thats why! thankyou!